# Which tense should be used after "It has been a (time expression since . .."?

Tags: tense

**"It has been a year since I started consulting Dr. Wade"**  or,  **"It has been a year since I have started consulting Dr. Wade"** ( I have found both simple past and present perfect being used on Google )

"It has been a year since I (**have been/am**) consulting Dr. Wade " ?

Answer (score 1):

"It has been  since" is referring to a point in the past. In fact, "since" always requires a specific time in the past, not a continued time period, as described [by Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/linking-words-and-expressions/since). A simple past is a better fit.

> It has been a year since I started consulting Dr Wade.
>
> It has been a year that I have been consulting Dr Wade.

In the first sentence, you are talking about your starting point of the consultation: a simple past event. In the second sentence, you are talking about your continued engagement up to now: a present perfect.